# 403 Forbidden You dont have permission to access storage folder

Tags: laravel, permissions, centos7, plesk

I have a project on product. I have run "php artisan storage:link" and symlink have created. I can upload file to storage but i cant download them. The project is working properly on local. When i run "ls -l" on public folder i get this output

```
                drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 css
            -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Jul  3 19:05 favicon.ico
            drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 images
            -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1823 Jul  3 19:05 index.php
            drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 js
            -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     133 Jul  6 14:49 mix-manifest.json
            -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      24 Jul  3 19:05 robots.txt
            drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 scripts
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      60 Jul  7 16:25 storage -> /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/storage/app/public
            -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7482034 Jul  3 19:05 storage.zip
            drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 styles
            drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  3 19:05 svg
```

And my .htaccess on  root is ;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

[image]

[image]

Centos 7 OS and plesk panel that i am using. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you still have SELinux enabled, I would see if the audit log picked up something with `audit2allow /var/log/audit/audit.log` to see if any _httpd_ permissions are off. I often find it to be a *httpd_* boolean or the file/directory context are wrong.

Comment: well the selinux is disabled and i couldnt find audit directory below var/log there is mostly plesk folders exist. And i am sorry maybe i couldn't understand you.